# Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 migration: IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor

Tags: spring, migration, tomcat7, tomcat8

I am facing the following problem. Using a compiled software I am trying to launch it on Tomcat 8 instead of Tomcat 7. After resolving some minor problems I get stuck at this one:

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ... Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor, but interface was expected*

Reading around, it seems like it comes from Spring version difference. Trouble is I'm not touching the application here at all. Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8 get exactly same program to launch.

Could I ask you for your suggestions on solving it?

Comment: Classloading orders might change between different versions. And apparently you have mixed jars in your application.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. How would you start tracking it. Mixed jars meaning pointing to different Spring or what?

Comment: Yes... Check your dependencies (the actual ones ending up in the war).

Comment: I am one step forward now. Your tip brought me closer to the solution, thank you! I no longer have this error, but for the reasons that I don't know, the application is not starting properly yet. Once I learn what went wrong, I'm gonna share the experience here.

Answer (score 1):

On the way of investigating the problem I've learned about this ticket: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57129

It looks like Tomcat 8, as opposed to earlier Tomcat version does not load classes alphabetically. In my project it caused a problem as libraries holding different versions of asm where used.

Note: In the ticket from above - raised to apache, someone links the workaround at https://github.com/openwide-java/tomcat-classloader-ordered. For me it did not work, though.

In the end we had to go through a complex work of removing dependencies and fixing the project up so that it relies on one lib version only.

Good luck for everyone struggling with similar stuff!